Databricks ui is different between different Azure Tenants with activated SCIM Integration
Databricks ui is different between different Azure Tenants with activated SCIM Integration.
The Problem is that we have enabled SCIM integration and synced couple of groups in both tenants however in one tenant I can import group from synced groups but on another ui I can only create a group and not import groups that are already synced in "https://accounts.azuredatabricks.net/users/groups".

and like this

Could you please help me to understand why?

Are these workspaces part of the same Azure Account?

Databricks Account console is linked to Azure portal > SCIM provider under Entra ID.
So whatever Users / Groups created under that SCIM will be automatically provisioned in your Databricks Account page, that you can eventually add it to your Workspace.

There are two tenants, Groups are created in Account page but I cannot add them here in the first case

This is because in one workspace you have enabled Unity Catalog (correctly) and in the second one no. Or, to be precise, you have attached a Unity Catalog metastore to the workspace.
With Unity Catalog a feature called Identity Federation gets enabled automatically, this is what you are saying in the screenshot below.
(I work for Databricks)

i know thanks :)
